# Browsersync remove port from url

Tags: webpack, browser-sync

I am trying to remove port number from url in Browsersync (with webpack).

```
new BrowserSyncPlugin({
    host: 'test.local',
    proxy: 'https://test.local',
    open: 'external',
    files: ['**/*.css', '**/*.php'],
    port: 80,
}),
```

This configuration opens `https://test.local:81`

When i delete port argument, it opens `https://test.local:3000`

Anyway it is adding port number to end of the url. Is possible to make it without port number? Like this `https://test.local`